# TS2339: Property 'props' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying access a property of an object which can be `{}`.

So I'm doing something like this:

```
// component is the object which can be emtpy {}
if (component.children) return method(component.children)
```

Although, even if I'm ensuring that `.children` is there, typescript complains that it does not exist (also in the if condition).

This is quite weird IMO, because if we're asserting that a property exists (or not) why would it complain?

---

Example:

```
type OtherType = { name: string };
type TestType = {} | OtherType;

function method(variable: TestType): string {
  if (!variable.name) return ''

  return variable.name;
}
```

This will throw `Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.` as it can be seen in [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

Comment: but the error says that your `component` is declared as simple empty object `{}` so when you do at the end `component.props`, that property does not exist. You should see this error with your IDE too, not at run time

Comment: then in typescript these strict checks on types are not so much useful as in JS. If you say that your argument should be a `ReactNode`, it cannot be `undefined`, this should trigger an error, so example you will never get the case where an empty string is returned

Comment: That would be fine if `{}` was the only possibility, but can be so many other objects that do contain `.props`. the `{}` is set on 1 of the possibilities `type ReactFragment = {} | ReactNodeArray;`, and even then it could be `ReactNodeArray` instead.

Comment: @quirimmo `ReactNode` can be `... | null | undefined`

Comment: yeah I am just looking now at the source code, that type is defined as: `type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;`

Comment: try to wrap your last if, inside something like `if (component instanceof ReactChild)` and see if the error disappears

Comment: didn't work, there's no ReactChild instance to compare with (only types).

Comment: if you travel back through the inheritance (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L82), it looks like it should have a `type` prop. Try something like `if( component.type === ReactChild )` or `if (component.type === 'ReactChild')`

Comment: but that is my problem, can't try to check any property because the `component` might be `{}`. The same error `Property 'type' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error makes sense — it's not safe to access a property that may not exist. Replace it with:

```
function method(variable: TestType): string {
  if ('name' in variable) {
      return variable.name
  }

  return '';
}
```

As to the first part of your question, It's hard to answer without knowing what `method` does.

Comment: This fixes it! thanks. You mention _it's not safe to access a property that may not exist_, can you explain this? or point to a post?

Comment: `OtherType` is a union of two object types. In unions types, it's only allowed to access properties that exist in both shapes — because we are 100% sure they will be there in runtime. If a property exists only in one scenario, we need to make sure we are indeed dealing with this scenario — we need to _discriminate_ the union to separate the two cases. In this case, `if ('name' in variable)` is enough proof for TypeScript. Within this `if` statement it knows it's safe to access `variable.name`.

Comment: What I don't understand is the check `if (variable.name)` not working as the `if ('name' in variable)`, both check if the property is defined (the first ensuring it doesn't convert to false). So what is different in the second approach?

Comment: I understand your point and I agree. It's just the way TypeScript works.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while coding with StencilJS. When you create a Web Component with StencilJS, you also define a "tag" attribute for it. Then you refer to it using that tag everywhere else in your project. For e.g. if your Web Component is CustomDropdown, you will have

```
    @Component({
    tag: 'custom-dropdown',
    styleUrl: 'customdropdown.scss',
    shadow: false
})
```

If you need to use this component in another component, you simply use the "tag":

```
    <custom-dropdown> etc... </custom-dropdown>
```

If you use

```
    <CustomDropdown>
```

you will get the above error on the attributes.

Comment: It is a similar issue, but it seems to be specific to StencilJS, I advise you to open a new question with the correct tags, you might be luckier.